# How to validate certificate using OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

Here's what I did to test if the certificate is valid with OpenSSL:

```
# Combine

me@VSPACE MINGW64 ~/Downloads/STAR_mynewdomain_com
$ cat STAR_mynewdomain_com.crt comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt comodorsaaddtrustca.crt  addtrustexternalcaroot.
crt > mynewdomain-ssl-bundle.crt

# Create PEM file

me@VSPACE MINGW64 ~/Downloads/STAR_mynewdomain_com
$ openssl x509 -inform PEM -in mynewdomain-ssl-bundle.crt > public.pem

# Validate Certificate

me@VSPACE MINGW64 ~/Downloads/STAR_mynewdomain_com
$ openssl verify public.pem
OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.mynewdomain.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error public.pem: verification failed
```

Not sure what I missed, but it won't say it's valid, but if I use the Digicert Windows Utility to check the certificate (`mynewdomain-ssl-bundle.crt`) certificate is valid.

Comment: What do you expect the `openssl x509` command to do? You indeed set the input format to PEM and the default openssl output format is also PEM... This command is likely to strip out the 2 last certificates and therefore the verification fails.